# How to run scrapy commands programmatically in windows through Java

Tags: java, scrapy

I have made a `scrapy` project which is running successfully but for this i have to invoke this like `scrapy crawl dmoz items.csv` through `cmd`. Now i want to make a ui for this, so that it can be done through ui and for this i want to use java.But in java when i am passing arguments like `activate scrapy` in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` this throwing a error like this

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "activate": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

What I can do ? is this the right approach because I am newbie in python but good in Java that's why i want to make ui in Java ?

This is my java code

```
final String dosCommand = "activate scrapy";
      try {
         final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            dosCommand);
         final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
         int ch;
         while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)ch);
         }
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: The error is telling you that the program activate is not found. Is activate in your exec path in windows? Otherwise you may need to place the full path, something like `dosCommand="C:\Temp\activate scrapy"`

Comment: hi this is conda command for this i don't know which path i have to provide ?

Comment: Ups I don't know conda, but I do know that what you are sending is a command called activate, then it will look in the variable %Path% to find any executable that is called activate and issue it. Hence you get the error that the system cannot find the file ;). Could it be you need to setup the environment first?